# Why does gitlab show more tabs than the one in the sublime editor?

Tags: git, sublimetext3

I write code in sublime with tab width:4. When I push my code to gitlab, it shows with 1 more tab in the indentation. What's wrong here ? How should I setup my sublime to prevent this ?

Comment: Are you using actual, physical tab characters? Physical tab characters have no size; it's up to the thing that is editing/displaying the file to interpret them correctly.

Comment: @OdatNurd, yes. What is the fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue you're having here is that you're using physical `tab` characters and not spaces for indentation. While a space character has a very definite width (one character), a `tab` character has no intrinsic width. It's a single character that means "insert a level of indent here".

How big that indent displays as is entirely controlled by whatever it is that's displaying the text. The general idea of using a physical `tab` in this manner is that each individual person can set the display size of the `tab` to whatever they like, and as a result the text of the file doesn't change, but it's display does. In contrast, using spaces for indent causes the physical file to look the same for everyone that views it, regardless of their settings.

While you have set `tab_size` to 4 in Sublime, that is of no consequence to GitLab (or any other editor or display mechanism for your file) because all the file contains is a single `tab` character with no defined width. It so happens that GitLab has a default tab size of 8 characters instead of 4.

Hence, it appears as if there is one extra tab everywhere, but in reality if you use your mouse to select your text a character at a time you'll see that the `tab` is actually 8 characters wide.

For GitLab, there's a setting that controls this:

1. Click on your profile picture in the top right and select `Settings`
2. In the menu along the left hand side of the settings page, select `Preferences`
3. In the section labeled behaviour, there's a setting for `Tab Size`; set that to your desired tab width and click `Save Changes` at the bottom of the window.

This particular setting is currently per-user and not per-project, so what you set here applies to everything across GitLab.

GitHub also has a default `tab` width of 8; however there you can append `?ts=4` to a URL displaying a file to alter the tab size on the fly.